# bash regular expression different formats

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I have used regular expression in my code like this: `.*[^0-9].*`

But recently I have seen some functions implemented like this: `*[!0-9]*` for the same purpose of first example, that is non-integer numbers.

So I confused what is the true form of regex and what is the difference of them.

can anybody help me in this issue?

Comment: [^0-9] is not for non-integer number; it is for non-number character.

Comment: I mean for recognizing numbers i have used this format before.

Comment: Can you give an example of each usage? That is, which utility/built-in used each one.

Comment: The second one is not a regular expression; it's a pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one regular expression - the first one. The second one is a glob pattern.

See regex(7) for the description of POSIX extended regular expressions supported by Bash:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html

See Bash manual for the description of glob patterns: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html

Bash uses regular expressions in [[…]] command only: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html

Bash uses glob patterns for everything else.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX defines:

1) two types of regular expressions: [BREs and EREs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). These are used by utilities / built-ins.

BREs are more restricted and exist for backwards compatibility and typing less on an interactive session. Avoid them if possible and use EREs instead, which are more flexible and PERL-like.

Some utilities allow you to choose between both types of regular expressions.
For example, `grep` matches BREs by default (backwards compatibility...), but you can make it match EREs with `-E`.

Use usually must quote those before passing them to utilities or the shell will filename expand them.

`.*[^0-9].*` could be both a BRE or an ERE. In both cases it means the same as the Perl regex, which is equivalent to the glob `*[!0-9]*`.

The main difference between BRE and ERE is that EREs add more useful Perl like special characters such as `(a|b)`, `a{m,n}`, `a+`, `a?`. Examples:

```
echo a | grep '(a|b)'
# output:
echo a | grep -E '(a|b)'
# output: a

echo a | grep 'a{1,2}'
# output:
echo a | grep -E 'a{1,2}'
# output: a
```

2) [Patterns Used for Filename Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13_02), also known as *globs* (used by the POSIX `glob` C function). These are usually expanded by the shell before going to the utilities and expand to match filenames. If you quote them they are don't expand anymore.

`*[!0-9]*` is must be a glob since BREs ane EREs use `^` instead of `!`.

```
echo *[!0-9]*
# output: filenames which are not numbers

echo '*[!0-9]*'
# output: *[!0-9]*
```